# Is there a budget fish-eye for Pentax Q system?

Tags: lens, pentax, fisheye, 3rd-party

I currently use a Pentax Q camera with the standard lens and I was wondering if anyone knows of a budget fish-eye lens that will fit the Q. I know Pentax does an official fish-eye lens but it's around £100 and as I don't use my camera often I'd like to spend less on a cheaper lens just to play about with.

I am a very amateur photographer who just enjoys taking the odd snap here and there so I'm not too fussed about having the highest quality lens or camera.

Does anyone know of any cheaper alternatives, even if they are unbranded Chinese lenses? I'm just something I can experiment with.

Comment: There is an adapter for Pentax K-mount lenses to the Q-mount, giving access to more lens options, but it's more expensive than the fish-eye and wouldn't make a lot of sense unless you had K-mount lenses already or were looking to buy a Pentax dSLR as well.

Comment: And mounting any APS-C fish-eye lenses on the Q is going to be a bit strange due to the crop factor - even taking the Pentax [10mm fisheye](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B000CNI016/ref=asc_df_B000CNI01614855106?smid=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&tag=cpbcouk-21&linkCode=asn&creative=22206&creativeASIN=B000CNI016), that's going to be ~50mm equivalent focal length, which is... a bit wierd for a fisheye.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any third parties making Q-mount lenses. Speculating not very wildly, the relatively tiny market for the Q, the significantly different sensor size and the need for the in-lens leaf shutter for Q mount lenses all make it not an attractive platform for third parties, so I wouldn't expect this to change any time soon.